# How do I Develop push notifications with multiple people?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

A group of friends and I are looking to start a company, and we wanted to develop our app (it uses push notifications) first. However, I'm the only one with a Apple Developer Account, and there's no way to sign the app and download the app onto a phone if the computer being used isn't mine. We looked into buying a program, but the only options we found were Individual and Enterprise. Enterprise seems like its only for 100+ people — is there no "under 50" or "under 10" developer program?

Comment: You need a company membership. This is different to enterprise (which is for companies to release their own internal apps outside the App Store)  with a company membership you can have multiple team members. If you don't yet have an incorporated company then you could get an individual membership and share the signing keys and login

Comment: How do I make a company membership?

Comment: You [enrol as an organization](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)

Comment: gotcha — so would this mean after i do this each of us can download and test the app?

Comment: An organisation enrolment means that you can have multiple team members developing the app

Comment: does this allow for xcode support? right now I've added my team members on app store connect but they aren't able to sign on xcode

Comment: For them to be able to sign you need to share the signing certificate